# Where does SQL_Variant datatype come from in select statement using LOGINPROPERTY

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In the below code I do not understand where SQL_Variant is coming from - The column it is complaining about is `LOGINPROPERTY([name], 'PASSWORDLASTSETTIME') AS LastChangeTime` According to MSFT documents this is a `DATETIME` column.

Where does the `SQL_Variant` datatype come from?

```
DROP TABLE #PasswordChange;
CREATE TABLE #PasswordChange (name VARCHAR(50),
lastPWChangeTS DATETIME,
PWhash VARBINARY(26));

INSERT INTO #PasswordChange (name,
lastPWChangeTS,
PWhash)
SELECT [name],
LOGINPROPERTY([name], 'PASSWORDLASTSETTIME') AS LastChangeTime,
LOGINPROPERTY([name], 'PASSWORDHASH') AS PWhash
FROM sys.syslogins
WHERE loginproperty([name], 'PASSWORDLASTSETTIME') > DATEADD(HOUR, -24, 
GETDATE());

Msg 257, Level 16, State 3, Line 6
Implicit conversion from data type sql_variant to datetime is not 
allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The return value depends on the input value, but the result set returns sql_variant to accommodate all possible return types.

You'll have to make some adjustments to your code.

```
INSERT INTO #PasswordChange
     ( name, lastPWChangeTS, PWhash )
SELECT  name,
        CONVERT(DATETIME, ISNULL(loginproperty([name], 'PASSWORDLASTSETTIME'), 0)) AS LastChangeTime,
        CONVERT(VARBINARY(26), LOGINPROPERTY(name, 'PASSWORDHASH')) AS PWhash
FROM    sys.syslogins
WHERE   CONVERT(DATETIME, loginproperty([name], 'PASSWORDLASTSETTIME')) > DATEADD(HOUR, -24, GETDATE());
```